# Accessing "test.html" page from the browser at the following url http://mysharepointservername.com/test.html

Tags: html, iis, sharepoint, browser

Which directory should I use to place test.html to access it via the browser by using the following url:

http://mysharepointservername.com/test.html ?

If I place the file to C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\80 , I get 404 not found error.

Is there another directory I should use to place test.html?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can create a module in sharepoint and place test.html under that module.

And in elements.xml write:

```
Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Module Name="CustomPage" Url="">
    <File Url="CustomPage\test.html" Name="test.html" Type="Ghostable" />
  </Module>
</Elements>
```

And deploy this module using feature.

In this way you can access the page  with http://mysharepointservername.com/test.html